# How to add (insert) view to the superview

Tags: iphone

I want to know how to add imageview to the super view.
this is how program works.
1.superview have childview
2.choose liitle picture from the childview
3.remove child view and send selected picture to the superview
I just dont know where to begin, please help me guys.

```
#import "SecondLevelView.h"
#import "StickerViewController.h"

@implementation SecondLevelView

-(IBAction)switchStickerView:(id)sender{

    StickerViewController *stickerController = [[StickerViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"StickerViewController" bundle:nil];

    self.stickerViewController = stickerController;
    [self.view insertSubview:stickerViewController.view atIndex:1];
    [stickerController release];
    [super viewDidLoad];

}
```

so this is rootview. it has toolbar to call stickerViewController. I draw picture for StickerViewcontroller through stickerView.h file. 
so, what Im stuck on is, when I choose picture from code in stickerview.m, I want ro send picture to secondlevelview.

Answer (score 0):

```
[viewToMove retain];  //since detaching from super will decrement retain count. 
UIView *myRootView = [viewToMove superview];
[viewToMove removeFromSuperview];
[myRootView addSubview: viewToMove];
[viewToMove release];
```

Comment: Please excuse my formatting. I'm submitting this from a phone and there is no option to correctly format that code.

Comment: myRootView can be obtained by `myRootView = [viewToMove superview];`

Comment: I'm sorry but I think I poorly described my situation above. actually viewcontrollerA has viewcontrollerB. viewcontrollerB using its view to draw little picture. so when the view picture selected, I put it on the imageview and try to send to superview. its shame on me but I really dont know how to use above code to my program. please help me!